# Regular expression in android for accept only English language

Tags: android, regex

I try

```
Pattern.matches("[A-Za-z]+"
```

and it still can accept other languages such as ฟฟฟฟabc or abcฟฟฟ

what should I do?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of "English language?" Do you mean [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)?

Answer (score 7):

```
^[A-Za-z]+$
```

Use start-of-string and end-of-string [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

If you don't, the regex does not have to match the *entire* string, but this is what you seem to want.

Comment: It still can accept other alphabet I think the method to define the regular in android is difference from unix, right?

Comment: This regex is so simple that it will work in *any* regex engine. You must be doing something else wrong. I guess you are just not using the library correctly, but without *a little* more context in your code sample, this is impossible to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working in UTF-8? Have you tried the \uFFFF, where FFFF is the hex representation of the Unicode character.

Comment: This is not a helpful suggestion.